# Vertx WebClient when I don't use the connection for a period of time, I need to re-establish the connection instead of using my configuration

Tags: vert.x, vert.x-webclient

```
val options =
    WebClientOptions().setMaxPoolSize(1000)
        .setKeepAlive(true)
        .setKeepAliveTimeout(60 * 10)
        .setTrustAll(true)
        .setPoolCleanerPeriod(1000 * 60 * 10)
        .setIdleTimeoutUnit(TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .setIdleTimeout(10)
        .setMaxWaitQueueSize(1000)
        .setConnectTimeout(1000 * 60 * 10)

webClient = WebClient.create(vertx, options)
vertx.http.clients.open-netsockets
```

It will return to 0 soon

Comment: did you make a request? It is a connection pool so it will grow and shrink on demand

Comment: I think that the basis of pool shrinkage is setPoolCleanerPeriod and setIdleTimeout, rather than irregular shrinkage. Do I have a wrong understanding

Answer (score 0):

as you set ConnectTimeout with huge number, you also need to increase also both these properties KeepAliveTimeout and setIdleTimeout.